# Prove that if $X \overset{d}{=} -X$ and $P(X=0)=0$ then $|X|$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(X)$ are independent.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

As in question - I need to prove that if $X \overset{d}{=} -X$ and $P(X=0)=0$ then $|X|$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(X)$ are independent. I do not even know where to start. I tried something like that:
$$P(|X|\leq k, \operatorname{sgn}(X) \leq \ell, X <0) = \cdots $$ but it gets me nowhere...

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing about an event of the form $\operatorname{sgn}(X) \le \ell$ is rather odd when the only two values that $\operatorname{sgn}(X)$ can have are $+1$ and $-1.$

First note that
$$
\Pr(\operatorname{sgn}(X) = +1) = \overbrace{\Pr(X>0) = \Pr(-X>0)}^{\large\text{since } X \, \overset d = \, -X} = \Pr(X<0) = \Pr(\operatorname{sgn}(X)=-1), \\[10pt]
\text{and therefore } \Pr(\operatorname{sgn}(X)=+1) = 1/2.
$$
Now suppose $A\subseteq (0,\infty).$ Notice that the event $\big[\,|X|\in A\ \&\ \operatorname{sgn}(X)=+1\big]$ is the same as the event $[X\in A].$ Then we have
\begin{align}
\Pr( |X| \in A\ \&\ \operatorname{sgn}(X)=+1) & = \Pr(X\in A) = \Pr(-X\in A) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(|X|\in A) \cdot \frac 1 2 \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(|X|\in A)\cdot \Pr(\operatorname{sgn}(X)=+1).
\end{align}
Thus the two events are independent. (And similarly with $-1$ instead of $+1.$)

Answer (score 3):

$$P(|X| \le t \mid \text{sgn}(X) = 1) = \frac{P(0 < X \le t)}{P(X > 0)} = 2 P(0 < X \le t) = P(|X| \le t) $$